# How to structure phpmyadmin sql database to allow many to many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am somewhat new to phpmyadmin and I am trying to come up with a way to logically structure a junction table to accomplish my task at hand.

I am making an employee timesheet web app. I currently have an employees table, projects table, and timesheets table. I am trying to think of the best way to structure a junction table of employees/projects to store what projects each employee would like to show up in their timesheets.

I created a php form that creates a table with all available projects and puts a checkbox next to each one so the employee can login with their userID and then manage what projects they are working on.

How should I set up my tables to allow an INSERT/UPDATE statement that adds/removes project association with each employee? I tried making employees_projects with primary key ID and foreign keys employeeID and projectID, but then I have no way of referencing if that association already exists (ie. I was thinking something like looping through my php POST results of selected checkboxes and querying INSERT INTO employees_projects VALUES ($eID,$pID) but this would not catch duplicate entries).

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a pivot table. For an example I'm going to use a user table and a group table, where users can be in many groups and each group can have many users. The table structure will look like this:

### User table

```
+----+------+-------------+
| ID | name |    email    |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | Foo  | foo@baz.com |
|  2 | Bar  | bar@baz.com |
+----+------+-------------+
```

### Group table

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| ID | group_name | group_access |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | Admins     |            1 |
|  2 | Users      |            0 |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

### Group_Users table

```
+----------+---------+
| group_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        2 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

You then set up foreign keys in the Group_Users table to link `group_id` to `ID` in the `group` table, and likewise for the `user_id` in the `user` table.

Finally to stop any duplicates you make a unique key across the two columns in the `group_users` table. This SQL would do that - `ALTER TABLE group_user ADD UNIQUE (group_id, user_id);`

Comment: Hmm that sounds similar to what I was considering. But based on your example, how would I build a query to both insert and update as necessary? Ie. if a user is not currently in a group, insert a new record with group_access = 1, but if a user leaves a group, simply update the group_access to 0?

Comment: Oops sorry, I just saw the last part of your comment. I will try this! Also, what exactly would the group_access column be used for? I considered putting it in the group_users table as a way to store relationships and just deactivate them rather than deleting/reinserting every time?

Comment: In my example group access would just be for permissions with an ACL, but you can create whatever columns you need for your application.